# Google Analytics User Management Insert User

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am using this endpoint to insert a user onto a Google Analytics account (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/insert)

I am getting back an error (just for this user):
`[{"message":"Value for field user.email = NAME@CLIENTDOMAINREDACTED.com is not valid.","domain":"global","reason":"invalidValue"}]`

I cannot see this error quoted anywhere else and it works for other email addresses. This one doesn't have whitespace at the beginning or end either.

Is this email banned somewhere? Is there any other reason for this potentially?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason was that this email address does not seem to be associated with a Google Account.

Which is strange since I also tried to add a random string of letters that is not associated with a Google Account and it let me do that!